# find all .txt files with certain string in filename and then read into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following incomplete code which I want to do the following

1. find all *.txt files in a folder of subfolders which has the the following keywords in the file name.
2. read the the contents of txt file to a dataframe.

```
import os 
import pandas as pd
  
path = os.getcwd() 

keywords = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']

result = {}  # dict store our results
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    for keyword in keywords:
        if keyword in filename:
            print(filename)
            df = pd.read_excel ('.txt')
```

Desired Output ( a list of files found and a dataframe containing the contents of all files)

```
test1 Dec 05, 2019 10-30-57.txt
test2 Dec 05, 2019 10-30-57.txt
test3 Dec 05, 2019 10-30-57.txt
```

The main problem is I dont know how to apply this to the main folder which has many sub folders.

Comment: If you want to open a file, you can give something like this: `df = pd.DataFrame(); for f in files_xls:  data = pd.read_excel(f, 'Sheet1');df = df.append(data)` If you want to append all of them to one dataframe. If you want separate, you create separate with name concatenated

Comment: For this with subdirectories you can use `os.walk()` which allows you to "walk" through the full directory tree iteratively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on my comment, I will provide an example:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

keywords = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']

frames = []
for path, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        if any(key in file for key in keywords) and file.endswith('.txt'):
            filename = os.path.join(path, file)
            print(filename)
            frames.append(pd.read_excel(filename))

full_df = pd.concat(frames, axis=0)
```

Here we are iterating through the directory structure using `os.walk()`, and then only printing and reading the files which satisfy your conditions. The files are read individually as dataframes and then concatenated into one final dataframe using `pd.concat()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. with your code I get the following error ``Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'Header L``. The actual file format is ``input5(f) Dec 05. 2019 10-30-57.txt``. I have tried removing ``(f)`` but does not make a difference....

Comment: I got this working with the following ``frames.append(pd.read_csv(filename,sep='none',header=None,engine='python'))``. However, I just need to find a way to remove the ``\t`` from the df in each row. I have tried ``sep=\t``but to no avail.

Comment: For clarity, where are the tabs (`\t`) showing up? I can probably modify my answer to include fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

I will leave you to decide how you will get to the file names from the directory.

If you want to create a dataframe for each filename, then you can use this code:

```
import pandas as pd
glb = globals()
keywords = ['test1','test2', 'test3']
filelist = ['your list of filenames']
i = 1
for filename in filelist:
    if any(k in filename for k in keywords):
        df = f'df{i}'
        glb[df] = pd.read_csv(filename)
        i+=1
```

The above code will create a dataframe df1, df2, .... for each file that has any of the words in list `keywords`. I am not creating the dataframe with the actual keyword. There may be occurrences where the same keyword is found in more than one  filename (ex: `test1-2021-01-12.txt, test1-2021-01-15.txt`. In this case, there are two files with the same `test1` keyword. So creating the second one will delete the contents of the first one.

I also don't want to create the dataframe with the filename. There maybe special characters or spaces in the filename. So we cannot create the filename as the dataframe. Instead, I am using `df` concatenated with a counter starting from 1.

The use of globals() allows you to create the variable and use it later. If you want to keep track of all the dataframes created, append the value of df to a list and then print them out or use the index of the list to navigate thru each of the dataframes.

If you want to read all these into a single dataframe, then the solution is very simple.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in filelist:
    data = pd.read_excel(filename)
    df = df.append(data)
```

Comment: I going to attempt to use ``os.walk`` to get the ``filelist``